# The variables are empty when foreach finishes

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code:

```
  function composeInsertSql($insertData)
  {
    $columns = '';
    $values = '';
    foreach($insertData as $data)
    {
      $columns .= $data[0].', ';
      if($data[2] == 1)
      {
        $values .= '"'.$data[1].'", ';
      }
      else if($data[2] == 2)
      {
        $values .= $data[1].', ';
      }
      else if($data[2] == 3)
      {
        $values .= 'md5("'.$data[1].'"), ';
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    $result['columns'] = rtrim($columns, ', ');
    $result['values'] = rtrim($values, ', ');
    return $result;
  }
```

The code works fine when it is an independent function, but inside a class It doesn't work.
When it is inside a class, the variables "values" and "columns" are empty when the foreach finishes. Inside the foreach I use echo and I can see their values, but when it finishes they are empty.

The call to this class function is made another class function in the same class:

```
  function genericInsert($table, $insertData)
  {
    $sqlData = self::composeInsertSql($insertData);
    $columns = $sqlData['columns'];
    $values = $sqlData['values'];
    $sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$columns.') values ('.$values.')';

    echo "$sqlInsert\n"; // borrar y descomentar las siguientes lineas.
```

Both functions are in the same class. The call to this functions is:

```
$db = new DB();
$dblink = $db->connect();

$insertData = array(
  array('paypal_id', '161411002', '2'),
  array('name', 'Marco', '1'),
  array('mail', 'marco@rarara.com', '1'),
  array('product_id', '1', '2'),
  array('profile_id', '1', '2'),
  array('insert_time', 'now()', '2'),
  array('state', '1', '0')
);

$db->genericInsert('user_client2', $insertData);
```

Comment: You last array haves the third value as `0` and inside your function, you have the conditions for values equals `1`, `2`, and `3`. You `else` condition ends your function returning `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a logic problem here. On your `$insertData` the last `array` is:

```
$insertData = array(
    array('state', '1', '0') <-- note the third item value is 0
);
```

And inside your function you have these conditions:

```
if($data[2] == 1)
else if($data[2] == 2)
else if($data[2] == 3)
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Note that if your `$data[2]`(array's third value) is not `1`, `2` or `3` your function will return `false`.

This might be breaking your logic. Try changing the `0` to `2`, seeing that it doesn't add quotes on your query and the second item is a `number` value.